# Has this (dwarf?) orchid gotten too much sun?

Tags: orchids

I have this small orchid which is actually doing really well. I noticed that the leaves are getting a little yellowish, has it been getting to much sun? it sits on a windows sill.

The leaves aren't droopy at all, just yellow.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchid leaves turning yellow is part of the normal plant cycle. As they grow new leaves, the old ones start to die. Perfectly normal.

However, yellow leaves is also a sign of over watering. Orchids are plants that are very tough, growing in unusual places, specifically in very tough environment where water is scarce. If you over water, you will cause root rot. 
Damaged roots can not take in water and nutrients to the leaves where food is manufactured (photosynthesis), leading to death.

Water once a week and make sure the roots do not stand in water. I soak my pots completely for 10 minutes/week myself.

You asked if it had too much sun.... probably!!  The best orchids actually grow in tree bark getting indirect sunlight.
Choose a south facing window and make sure the light is not direct.

If you have root rot, you can try to take it out of pot, cut the bad roots out then repot. 
However I would just move it first, stop watering for a while and observe what happens. I see you have a stem and buds. If the plant is dying, that’ll turn black and die very quickly, out of survival.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have put it out of direct sunlight  and i'll keep checking on it. I usually water it once a week anyways.